# Catch shutdown console in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, signals

I'd like to catch a Shutdown done by a user in a Linux terminal, such as:

```
sudo shutdown
```

I'm using the following C++ code:

```
myAct.sa_handler = myStructure::mySignalHandler;
sigaction(mySignal, &act, NULL);
```

And I'm using a script to send a `mySignal` signal.

However, using a script implies to modify the system's main files, and I don't want that.

Is there another solution to catch a shutdown signal via a C++ code in Linux ?

Answer (score 3):

As per the man page, when shutdown is run, all processes are sent a SIGTERM. So if you write your own signal handler for SIGTERM, you should not need to include any other scripts.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have enough time to do my actions before the systems shuts down ...

Comment: There should be a gap between sending SIGTERM and SIGKILL but this can be very short. In any event this is a system thing which your process has no control over.